# Maintenance plan using cursor statement

Tags: sql-server, cursors

I have a cursor which gives parameters to columns to executes the stored procedure in order to update my table. Cursor statement is following:

```
declare @ColumnName nvarchar(30)
declare @ColumnID int

declare UpdateCurs cursor
for 
select ColumnName , ColumnID from MyTable

open UpdateCurs 

fetch next from UpdateCurs into @ColumnName , @ColumnID 

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

  execute dbo.UpdateMyTable @ColumnName , @ColumnID 

fetch next from UpdateCurs into @ColumnName , @ColumnID 

END

close UpdateCurs 
deallocate UpdateCurs
```

When I execute the statement directly, it works fine, but when I create maintenance plan via "Execute T-SQL statement" and schedule job, the job results with  following error:

> failed with the following error: "Invalid column name 'ColumnID'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly."

One thing I can`t understand that, if there is something wrong with my statement, why it is executed without problems directly and gives error on Maintenance plan ?
I will appreciate your thoughts on this

Comment: Is your maintenance plan pointing to the correct database?  Have you tried fully qualifying your table objects?  <Database>.<Schema>.TableOrView to make sure you are referencing the correct objects?

Comment: I just have paid attention to database connection after your comment. It is so silly, but I didn`t spell "use databasename" in my query, that`s why my job wasn`t executing. Sorry, and thank you for pointing to the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are either connecting to the correct database (`USE <database>`) or using fully qualified names in your maintenance plan.